# Finding the coefficient in expansion

Tags: combinatorics

In the sum $\sum a_n = a_1+a_2+a_3+\cdots +a_n$, the coefficient of $a_i$ is 1

In the sum $\sum \sum a_n = a_1+(a_1+a_2)+(a_1+a_2+a_3)+\cdots +(a_1+a_2+a_3+\cdots+a_n)$, the coefficient of $a_i$ is $n-i+1$

Like wise if we continue for $k$ times, what will be the coefficient of $a_i$ of resultant series.

Comment: For the next iteration do we write $a_1 + (a_1 + a_1 + a_2) + (a_1 + a_1+a_2 + a_1+a_2+a_3) +\ldots$ ? Or do you group first to get $na_1 + (n-1)a_2 + \ldots$ so it's $na_1 + (na_1 + (n-1)a_2) + \ldots$

Comment: $a_1+(a_1+(a_1+a_2))+(a_1+(a_1+a_2)+(a_1+a_2+a_3))+…$

Comment: Then the coefficient (read from right to left, or in other words of $a_{n+1-i}$) is $\sum_{k=1}^i$ of the previous coefficient. So $1\to \sum_{k=1}^i 1 = i\to \sum_{k=1}^i k = i(i+1)/2 \to \sum_{k=1}^i k(k+1)/2 = \ldots$ You can express this in terms of binomial coefficients.

Comment: @Winther is there any formula using binomial coefficients other than summation?

Comment: I was just pointing out the pattern that arises. The final result should be something like $C[a_{k};\ell] = {n-k+\ell\choose \ell}$ (the coefficient of $a_k$ at the $\ell$'th iteration with $\ell = 0$ corresponding to $1$'s). Sure there is a simple induction proof to be made here, but I'm too tired to think about it.

Comment: (1) The expression "$\sum\sum a_n$" is **meaningless** unless you put some indices and limits of summation there on both sigmas. (2) Come to think of it, the claim that "$\sum a_n=a_1+a_2+a_3+\cdots+a_n$" is highly questionable too, for the same reason. Note that, for example, $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n a_i=a_1+a_2+a_3+\cdots+a_n$, while $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n a_n=a_n+a_n+a_n+\cdots+a_n=na_n$. And we can make up tons of different variations, say $\sum\limits_{i=1}^1 a_n=a_n\neq a_1+a_2+a_3+\cdots+a_n$.

Comment: But, I thought that, it is clear from given pattern without any ambiguity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As zipirovich mentions, the symbol $\Sigma$ is typically meaningless without indices, but you have defined it as an operator:$$
\Sigma a_n = \sum_{i = 1}^n a_i = a_1 + a_2 + ... + a_n
$$
This is fine but you ought to be clear you're not using the notation in the standard way.
We define $\Sigma^k$ to represent iterating $\Sigma$ $k$ times. Define $\sigma^k_i(n)$ to be the coefficient of $a_i$ in $\Sigma^k a_n$, i.e. $$
\Sigma^k a_n = \sum_{i = 1}^n \sigma_i^k(n) a_i
$$
We trivially observe that $\sigma_i^1(n) = 1$. Now observe,
$$
\Sigma^k a_n = \Sigma^{k-1}(\Sigma a_n) = \sum_{i=1}^n \sigma_i^{k-1}(n)\Sigma a_i = \sum_{i=1}^n \sigma_i^{k-1}(n)\sum_{j = 1}^i a_j = \sum_{j = 1}^n\left(\sum_{i=j}^n\sigma_i^{k-1}(n)\right)a_j
$$
Thus we must have the recursion on $\sigma$:
$$
\sigma_j^k(n) = \sum_{i=j}^n\sigma_i^{k-1}(n)
$$
For $k = 2$, this yields $\sigma_j^2(n) = \sum_{i=j}^n\sigma_i^{1}(n) = \sum_{i=j}^n 1 = n - j + 1$. For $k = 3$, we must have
$$
\sigma_j^3(n) = \sum_{i=j}^n(n - i + 1) = (n - j + 1) + ... + 3 + 2 + 1 = \frac{(n - j + 2)(n - j + 1)}{2} = T_{n - j + 1}
$$
where $T_n$ is the $n$th triangular number.
In general, it seems that the coefficients will be closely related to [simplex numbers](https://oeis.org/wiki/Simplicial_polytopic_numbers), which can be extracted from Pascal's triangle. I believe that it should be straightforward to show that $\sigma_j^k(n)$ is the $(n - j + 1)$th $k$-simplex number.

Comment: Where can I find the standard notation for this multiple summation?

Comment: I don't think I've seen any notation other than just writing a summation. But it is totally fine to define new notation, you just have to be clear that you're doing that, and be 100% clear what the notation means.